# Join `fields` and `expand` into `fields`

Tags: php, yii, yii2

I've started to use `Yii2` framework, and to include computed fields from the table other than to what the model maps to I have to use `expand` on the client. I think this is wrong since in this way a client gains redundant knowledge about server side. Is it possible to join all fields into `fields`?

Comment: please show your related model and describe better your goal...

Comment: What do mean with 'expand' and 'fields'?

Comment: @robsch, here is how my URL now looks like `/v1/articles?fields=id,title&expand=additionalTitle`. I want to be able to specify `additionalTitle` with fields like this `/v1/articles?fields=id,title,additionalTitle`